# CSS Position fixed child in a transformed parent with overflow-y auto, child moves when scrolling parent

Tags: css, scroll, position, transform, fixed

I'm trying to use a pseudo after element to create a gradient at the end of a div to indicate that it's scrollable. Using `transform: translateZ(0);` on the div allows the psuedo element to use `position: fixed;` to be stuck to the bottom of the element. However, once you start scrolling, the pseudo element scrolls up along with the content of the div. Is it possible to have this element stick to the bottom of this div while scrolling (aside from using `position: sticky;` which i'm avoiding for browser support reasons)?

Here's a fiddle of what I've got right now:
https://jsfiddle.net/ebL485q9/2/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to wrap your scrollable content inside another container `div` and change the position for your gradient from fixed to absolute. Apply your max-height changes to the outer container. That way, your outer container controls the open and close and the inner container always remains with a fixed height.

Updated fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/pv72xbog/

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: thaaaaank you so much! this worked like a charm. it also helped me realize that part of my initial problem was that the parent element of the pseudo element had position relative applied to it when it needed to be reverted back to static. thx so much!

Comment: @Lisa great. I am glad it all worked out!. Please do upvote and mark as selected answer in case my answer worked for you. Cheers.